# UV Unwrapping: How to get "fresh mesh sphere"-like UV results on a bottle?

Tags: uv

When I first create a sphere, it has a nice UV map, like this:
[image: Original sphere UV]

However, when I try UV unwrapping with identical seams, I get this:
[image: UV unwrap with seams.]

Using cylinder or sphere projection does better, but it's still wonky at the edges:
[image: Cylinder projection]

I am currently trying to UV unwrap a bottle, and I'd like the "fresh mesh" UV style, where the map spreads out over the image rather than trying to make individual faces less contorted, thus making the texture easier to paint as a whole in an external image program.

One thing I've tried is arranging the UV vertices of the bottle edge (before a Screw modifier) to be in a straight line, then letting the Screw modifier turn it into a Grid. This sort-of works, but the straight-line arrangement doesn't work well for portions of the bottle that are horizontal, and leaves them with zero texture height. If I had a way to evenly distribute the rings of the bottle from top to bottom on the texture, that would do.

Oddly enough, the curve this bottle came from seemed to have this UV automatically, but I could not preserve it when converting to mesh.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using third part addons, you could use UV Squares by Radivarig. ([Github Page](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares)) . Use To Grid By Shape then Pack UV's. Make sure Constrain To Image Bounds is on to easily scale to the whole UV.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks viable. I’ll try it out! :-) As for links, they are completely legal on Blender Stackexchange as long as you label them properly AFAIK. They have a tool to help you add links.

Comment: Can confirm with respect to links.  The only links that are not allowed are those that are actually spam.  That's part of why ["link only"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) answers are discouraged.